# Flask internal server error, how to get error logs?

Tags: nginx, flask

I have this flask application I deployed using Nginx, I get Internal server error in production but in developement it's fine. Is there a way to see what might be the error ? (log file or something)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in your Nginx' error log.

e.g. `/var/log/nginx/error.log` or `journalctl -u nginx`.